# Is the given statement correct? I'm confused, if it should be this kind or these kinds only

Tags: grammar

"He likes (these kinds/this kind) of Books."

Comment: Perhaps a little more context would help. Is there more than one book at hand? Is there more than one kind of book? They are correct but distinct statements.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them can be correct depending on what you want to say.

**He likes this kind of books.** Here all books have the same type. For example, those are all novels.

**He likes these kinds of books.** Here the books can have different types. For example, some books are novel whereas some other are Science fiction or other kinds of books.

Comment: There are science fiction novels, but you make a good point.

Comment: Hello, Bob. Please don't give 'answers' on ELU to questions unsuited to a website aimed at linguists.